# Query Activity of token access from login.windows.net

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting an access token from Azure AD B2C via `https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}/oauth2/token` 
using the password grant passing in username and password.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Resource = https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_id={clientId}&&grant_type=password&username="{username}"&password="{password}"&scope=openid"
```

The token is being returned but how would I pull the activity surrounding these token access activity, from Azure Graph?

Is that possible, if so how?

Comment: Azure AD B2C has a great doc on [how to do graph api calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) that may help out.

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is to get the activities(such as query operation) with specific access token using graph api , there is no such rest api supports that  . If i misunderstand your requirement , please feel free to let me know .